# boxed argument of a dispatchable

Tags: frame

there are cases when we want to `Box` an argument of a dispatchable. One such case is when the type is large, for instance, `xcm::MultiLocation` and we do not want to blow the size of `Call` type.

these types might be exposed as generic types via the pallet's config. in this situation, we technically have two ways to box that type:

1. on a pallet level: `fn do_something(..., asset: Box<Config::AssetKind>)`
2. on a client level: `impl Config { AssetKind = Box<MultiLocation>}`

the second option seems incorrect to me, at least because a library/pallet might not anticipate it, and we're somewhat misrepresenting what `AssetKind` truly is in this context.

do you see any concrete reasons to avoid `option 2`? or perhaps reasons why it might be fine?

let's consider a case when `AssetKind` is referenced in one of the events like `Created {asset: Config::AssetKind}` and stored in a storage item. also let's thing about a chain metadata.

from rust perspective, it appears that most cases would be handled since a boxed type would eventually be dereferenced.

Comment: With option 2 the user of the pallet gets full control, where as with option 1 the user of the pallet is forced to box. I would suggest that substrate pallets should be as un-opinionated as possible given that they could be used in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 1):

one reason I see not to use `option 2` relates to what I've already mentioned in the questions. In this case, we misrepresent what `AssetKind` is, which leads to some problems.

let's examine the example:

```rust
mod pallet_dream {
  ..
  pub trait Config {
    ..
    AssetKind: ..,
    Assets: fungibles::Inspect<.., AssetId = Self::AssetKind>, // (1)
  }

  impl<AssetKind = Config::AssetKind> 
   frame_support::Pay<AssetKind> for Pallet { // (2)
    ...
  }
}

mod wizard {
  trait Magic {
    fn leviosa();
  }
  ...
  impl<
    AssetKind, 
    From: frame_support::Pay<AssetKind>, // (3)
    To: frame_support::Oven<AssetId = Self::AssetKind>> 
     Magic for Burn {

  }
}
```

in case if `AssetKind = Box<...>`,

(1) any bounds within the pallet that reference that `AssetKind` will expect implementation over a Boxed type. this will make the usage of any common implementations impossible since they implemented over an actual type, not a box of it.

(2) any implementation the pallet provides for some low level contract (aka trait) which references the `AssetKind` will result an implementation over `Box` of `AssetKind`.

(3) if a general implementation like `Burn` is supplied with `Pay` implemented over `Box`, then an implementation of `Oven` also has to be defined over `Box`.